# Get details from paypal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

Is it possible to have a user sign into mywebsite via paypal and have the website retrieve the user's paypal postal address?

Comment: Khou, You only have 57% accceptance rate, don't forget to accept the answers that help you the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are possibilites to do PayPal integrations. See their [PayPal SOAP API Overview](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture). I've mainly seen this being used for validating and charging credit cards.

And there are alternatives that lets the users login to paypal but you have to re-direct them to paypal first. There are ways to get the adress that they provided in the purchase but you cannot authenticate them on PayPal via your site.

The *[Website PayPal Payments Pro](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPWebsitePaymentsPro)* allows for some additional features.

> Express Checkout lets you accept
>   PayPal payments on your website. Your
>   customers benefit because paying for
>   items is fast. They don't have to
>   spend time typing in financial and
>   shipping information because their
>   information is already stored in their
>   PayPal account.
>
> 1. Your customer chooses to pay with PayPal by entering their email address
>      and PayPal password, without leaving
>      your website.
> 2. Your customer makes the payment using PayPal.
> 3. The payment information is sent to PayPal using PayPal Express Checkout
>      API operations.
> 4. The funds from the transaction are sent to your PayPal account.

**But** it seems you cannot let the users login and just retreiv their information without performing a purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this question, but it is possible to get the postal address without forcing people to make a purchase. You simply need to use the Advanced Personal Data API endpoint. The steps are as follows:

1) Use the permissions API to get an access token for your user. Be sure to ask for the Advanced User Data permission.

2) Once you've got the token, build an advanced personal data request using the signature you'll get from the oauth token. This should include address information.